# Styled components's 'css' prop with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, styled-components

`styled-components` have a plugin that allows for the following:

```
<div
  css={`
    background: papayawhip;
    color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text};
  `}
/>
```

Is there any way I can tell TypeScript `css` is a valid property on all elements?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add following line to a TypeScript file inside your project as described in [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31245):

```
// e.g. src/global.d.ts

import {} from "styled-components/cssprop"
// or TS 3.8+
import type {} from "styled-components/cssprop"
```

Alternatively you can manually augment the `react` module type declaration - copy/paste contents from `"styled-components/cssprop"` to above file:

```
import { CSSProp } from "styled-components"

interface MyTheme {} // declare custom theme type

declare module "react" {
  interface Attributes {
    css?: CSSProp<MyTheme>
  }
}
```

Latter variant will also allow you to customize the `css` prop theme type.

Comment: The alternative solution worked for me. I declared that inside `styled.d.ts`. Thanks 

Comment: Adding same import at the top in your main App.tsx file, also worked for me.