# TypeScript issue with styled-component's "css" prop and Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm having issues with enabling styled-component's `css` prop in TypeScript as soon as I import something from Storybook, because Storybook depends on `@emotion/core`, whose type declaration defines Emotion's own `css` prop. The error stems from the fact that the two `css` prop types being incompatible.

I'm familiar with the [recommended way](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31245#issuecomment-446011384) of enabling the `css` prop in TypeScript (including the [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60952710/styled-componentss-css-prop-with-typescript)), as well as suggestions on [how to handle](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31245#issuecomment-780019806) the Storybook problem explained above.

This is the application code, `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { css } from 'styled-components'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <h1
      css={css`
        color: red;
      `}
    >
      Hello world!
    </h1>
  )
}
```

and this is the type declaration, `styled-components.d.ts`, which contains the attempted fix:

```
import { CSSProp } from "styled-components";

// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31245#issuecomment-780019806

declare module 'react' {
  interface DOMAttributes<T> {
    css?: CSSProp
  }
}
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicAttributes {
      css?: CSSProp
    }
  }
}
```

This works until I import something in `index.tsx` from Storybook which imports `@emotion/core`, for example:

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react'
// ...
```

Then TypeScript fails with the following errors:

```
index.tsx:8:7 - error TS2322: Type 'FlattenSimpleInterpolation' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationWithTheme<any>'.
  Type 'readonly SimpleInterpolation[]' is not assignable to type 'ObjectInterpolation<undefined>'.
    Types of property 'filter' are incompatible.
      Type '{ <S extends SimpleInterpolation>(predicate: (value: SimpleInterpolation, index: number, array: readonly SimpleInterpolation[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: SimpleInterpolation, index: number, array: readonly SimpleInterpolation[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): SimpleInterpolation[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | undefined'.
        Type '{ <S extends SimpleInterpolation>(predicate: (value: SimpleInterpolation, index: number, array: readonly SimpleInterpolation[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: SimpleInterpolation, index: number, array: readonly SimpleInterpolation[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): SimpleInterpolation[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.

8       css={css`
        ~~~

  node_modules/@emotion/core/types/index.d.ts:84:5
    84     css?: InterpolationWithTheme<any>
           ~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'css' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>'

styled-components.d.ts:7:5 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'css' must be of type 'InterpolationWithTheme<any>', but here has type 'CSSProp<any> | undefined'.

7     css?: CSSProp
      ~~~

  node_modules/@emotion/core/types/index.d.ts:84:5
    84     css?: InterpolationWithTheme<any>
           ~~~
    'css' was also declared here.

styled-components.d.ts:13:7 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'css' must be of type 'InterpolationWithTheme<any>', but here has type 'CSSProp<any> | undefined'.

13       css?: CSSProp
         ~~~

  node_modules/@emotion/core/types/index.d.ts:96:7
    96       css?: InterpolationWithTheme<any>
             ~~~
    'css' was also declared here.
```

[Here's the CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-easley-5g3so?file=/index.tsx) created from [this repository](https://github.com/silvenon/repro-ts-sc-css-storybook) which reproduces this issue.

Comment: I suggest cloning your reproducible example over to [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: @MikeS. here's [the CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-easley-5g3so?file=/index.tsx) as I'm not familiar with Stackblitz, I hope that helps 

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the `styled-components` library, it seems that you should be importing `style` rather than `css`.

I created an example showing how to do this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-1xkww4?file=/src/App.tsx

Alternatively, you could try casting `css` as something else, although I'm not sure it would help with the type definition conflict you're having.

```
import { css as StyledCss } from 'styled-components';
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by `style`? Did you mean `styled`?

Btw, based on the documentation it looks like the `css` is no longer needed at all for the `css` prop, not sure when that happened: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop But type checking works if I pass a regular string instead of using the `css` import.

Comment: If you would care to find out what happened there, in which version this changed and why, and post this in a new answer, I'd mark it as correct. I'm not using styled-components anymore so I have low motivation.

Comment: It looks like you are not using styled-components properly. See this: https://styled-components.com/

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Css } from 'styled-components'

export default function App() {
  return (
    
    
    <Css
     color={"red"}
      className={`${classes}`}
      {...props}
    >
 
     <h1>
      Hello world!
    </h1>
    </Css>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).